# ¿Cómo obtengo los datos de una tercera tabla con Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy trabajando con ***Eloquent*** en *Laravel 7*.
Tengo 3 tablas: países, estados, regiones, donde un país tiene 1 o varios estados y un estado tiene 1 o varias regiones.

Tengo que imprimir los nombres de las regiones de un país, tengo la ID de ese país.

Estoy usando la siguiente consulta:

```
$countryID = 1;
$regions = Country::with([
    'states:id,name,country_id', 
    'states.regions:id,name,state_id'
])
    ->where('id', '=', $countryID)
    ->first();
```

Tengo un resultado como este:

```
App\Models\Addresses\Country {#4085
     id: 1,
     name: "España",
     created_at: "2021-01-05 00:00:00",
     updated_at: null,
     states: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4314
       all: [
         App\Models\Addresses\State {#4317
           id: 1,
           name: "Andalucía",
           country_id: 1,
           regions: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4390
             all: [
               App\Models\Addresses\Region {#4407
                 id: 14,
                 name: "Almería",
                 state_id: 1,
               },
               App\Models\Addresses\Region {#4408
                 id: 15,
                 name: "Cádiz",
                 state_id: 1,
               },
               ...
```

No se es como imprimir los nombres de las regiones a partir del resultado.

> Editado

Las relaciones están establecidas en los modelos: en **Country** `hasMany` a **State** y de éste `hasMany` a *Region*. En **Region** `belongsTo` a **State** y en este `belongsTo` a **Country**.

La query la hice en *[tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#tinker)* y trate de acceder directamente e imprimir los nombres de las regiones de un país (en realidad lo que necesito es un método que me devuelva directamente las regiones de un país). Se que a obteniendo un objeto `Country` puedo imprimir los datos de las regiones a partir de sus relaciones, con algo así:

```
foreach ($country->states as $state) {
    foreach ($state->regions as $region) {

        echo $region->name . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

o como guardar esos nombres, en un array o colección por ejemplo para devolverlos con un método. La pregunta sería **¿hay una forma directa o hay que pasar por los bucles para obtener los datos de las regiones de un país?**

Comment: Obtenerlos en la consulta o en tu vista?, Puedes explicar mejor el problema?

Comment: Según he entendido quieres desde una consulta a la tabla de países mostrar las regiones directamente en tu vista, verdad? Si no me equivoco y es así antes de nada tienes que tener en tu modelo la relación hasMany de países a Estados y de Estados a regiones y la relación belongsTo de regiones a Estados y de Estados a países. Una vez tengas eso deberías hacer un ::find($id) de la tabla países y devolverla a la vista con el return. Ya en la vista con un foreach de pais->estados as estado y otro (dentro del anterior) de estados->regiones as region podrías obtener todos los estados y regiones

Comment: De ese país....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estos casos, me parece que lo apropiado sería una relación: [tiene muchos a través de](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), estableciendo lo siguiente:

- En el modelo `Country`, declaramos una relación de este tipo:

  ```
  public function regionsInCountry()
  {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Region::class, State::class);
  }
  ```
- Entonces la consulta, se puede componer de esta forma:

  ```
  $regionsInCountry = Country::with('regionsInCountry')->findOrFail($idCountry);
  ```

Lo anterior te debería estar devolviendo:

- Un objeto con todos los atributos del *country* en cuestión
- Una colección con todas las *regions* asociadas

Comment: Es lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias. Creo que se limita a conectar dos tablas con una intermedia. Por ejemplo con dos en medio, no funcionaría (para los datos de una cuarta tabla "cities"...). La doc para este tipo de relación esta disponible desde Laravel 5.1 (para quien le sirva): https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through